# Atividade de prolog

Tags: prolog

**Pergunta:** Defina o predicado ultimo(L,U), que determina o último item U numa lista L de números inteiros. Por exemplo, ultimo([1,3,5],U), resulta em U=5. E verifique se o último valor é menor que 10.

```
% fatos
ultimo([Fim], Fim).
ultimo([_|Fim], Ultimo) :- ultimo(Fim, Ultimo).
```

Contudo, não estou conseguindo verificar se o último valor é menor que 10.

Answer (score -2):

tudo beleza?
olha só, no fim da regra você pode por uma comparação:

`ultimo(Fim, Ultimo), 'variavel'+'operador'+'numero ou comparação'.`

testei aqui e funcionou.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).